# Getting the filenames of all files in a folder

Tags: java, file, directory, filenames

I need to create a list with all names of the files in a folder.

For example, if I have:

```
000.jpg
012.jpg
013.jpg
```

I want to store them in a `ArrayList` with `[000,012,013]` as values.

What's the best way to do it in Java ?

PS: I'm on Mac OS X

Answer (score 831, accepted):

You could do it like that:

```
File folder = new File("your/path");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
  if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
    System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
  } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
    System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
  }
}
```

Do you want to only get JPEG files or all files?

Comment: Yup there isn't but dealing with extensions is dependent on the extensions present cos files maybe present without extensions too.

Comment: btw if you want the current folder you can use `File folder = new File (".");` ... than the same. example `new File("./"+your_file);`

Comment: @RoflcoptrException One doubt. Does this listofFiles[i] points to the first file in the folder (last created), or the last file (first created) ?

Comment: in my folder are only *.xml files, is there any option to check that only those should be considered as files?

Comment: Just a suggestion, you could also use an enhanced for loop, like this: `for (File file : listOfFiles)`. Then you simply reference `file` in each iteration instead of `listOfFiles[i]`.

Comment: How can get specify extension to get .jpg files?

Comment: If you want filter out only .JPG files and sort the result in oldest file first, you can use it like this:

```File dir = new File("/your/path");
    FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*.JPG", IOCase.INSENSITIVE);  // For taking both .JPG and .jpg files (useful in *nix env)
    File[] fileList = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
        if (fileList.length > 0) {
            /** The oldest file comes first **/
            Arrays.sort(fileList, LastModifiedFileComparator.LASTMODIFIED_COMPARATOR);
        }
    //filesList now contains all the JPG/jpg files in sorted order```

Comment: @JustinGeorge From the JavaDocs it says that "There is no guarantee that the name strings in the resulting array will appear in any specific order; they are not, in particular, guaranteed to appear in alphabetical order."

Answer (score 158):

Create a [`File`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object, passing the directory path to the constructor. Use the `listFiles()` to retrieve an array of `File` objects for each file in the directory, and then call the `getName()` method to get the filename.

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();


File[] files = new File("/path/to/the/directory").listFiles();
//If this pathname does not denote a directory, then listFiles() returns null. 

for (File file : files) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        results.add(file.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: You should actually call `listFiles()` ;)

Comment: @Progman Could be helpful. :)

Comment: in my folder are only *.xml files, is there any option to check that only those should be considered as files?

Comment: You can put a filter on listFiles so as to only return files with a certain extension
              `File[] files = new File("/path/to/the/directory").listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                        return name.endsWith(".xml");
                    }
                }); `

Comment: What if I want to both *.xml & *.txt files ? @IanB

Comment: @sumitkanoje you would change the filter to be return name.endsWith(".xml") || name.endsWith(".jpg")

Comment: File[] files = new File(fullPath).listFiles();
 List<String> names = Arrays.asList(files).parallelStream().map(file -> file.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: You can filter files using *lambda* expression (Java 8+): `File[] files = new File("path/to/dir").listFiles((dir, name) -> name.endsWith(".xml"));`

Comment: I was hoping that using filter does some sort of intelligent buffering but taking a look at java8 implementation of list(FilenameFilter filter) I am a little bit disappointed that it just do something like File root=File("/path/to/the/directory"); foreach(String filename : root.list()){accept(root,filename)} and then convert the result from List<String> to String[].

Answer (score 72):

Here's how to look in the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).

First, you're dealing with IO, so look in the `java.io` [package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html).

There are two classes that look interesting: [FileFilter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html) and [FileNameFilter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html). When I clicked on the first, it showed me that there was a a `listFiles()` method in the [File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class. And the documentation for that method says:

> Returns an array of abstract pathnames
>   denoting the files in the directory
>   denoted by this abstract pathname.

Scrolling up in the `File` JavaDoc, I see the constructors. And that's really all I need to be able to create a `File` instance and call `listFiles()` on it. Scrolling still further, I can see some information about how files are named in different operating systems.