# Parsing multiple file names(doc) in java

Tags: java, parsing

I am trying to parse multiple file names(doc file)in java.
How should I go about doing this?

I asked a previous post and got a answer on how to parse a file name in java.
Thanks for that.

So in a directory, I have multiple files(with different names). For instance, there are files

```
AA_2322_1

AA_2342_1

BB_2324_1

CC_2342_1
```

I want to parse the middle 4 digit-5digit numbers only.

Comment: please say how you have all of your filenames stored.  Do you just have a directory name, a File object, a String[] of all the filenames?

Comment: Why did you ask the same thing again? In what way is the original answer not sufficient?

Comment: Saved them in a directory. There are multiple files in the directory.

Comment: So you have the directory filename?

Comment: Yes. If I set the position to directory filename, would it just parse all the files inside?

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/read-all-files-in-a-folder?lq=1

Comment: Why not use a regex and match the group of `[0-9]{4,5}`. That will match a group of numbers 4-5 digits in length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a directory C:\XYZ with the files you listed above, with .doc extensions on them.  Taking advantage of a FileFilter, you can get a list of the numbers you are looking for with the following code:

```
File directory = new File("C:/XYZ");

final ArrayList<String> innerDigits = new ArrayList<String>();

FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        if (!pathname.isFile() || !pathname.getName().endsWith("doc"))
            return false;

        // Extract whatever you need from the file object
        String[] parts = pathname.getName().split("_");
        innerDigits.add(parts[1]);

        return true;
    }
};

// No need to store the results, we extracted the info in the filter method
directory.listFiles(filter);

for (String data : innerDigits)
    System.out.println(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Getting the filenames of all files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694385/getting-the-filenames-of-all-files-in-a-folder) - Use this question to get the name of all the files in the directory. Then use the `String.split()` function to parse the file names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` method

```
String[] parts = filename.split("_");
```

Now you need parts[1]