# how to play random .wav sounds?

Tags: random, actionlistener

I have a group of .wav sounds which are contained in a folder within the package.
In the following code It will always play the same .wav sound every time the button is pressed. how to to add the Random function to read from the folder and play a different sound each time the button is pressed.

```
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if (e.getSource() ==  Button)
                     play("/nameofthefolder/nameofsound.wav");

                    }
```

Comment: try to get all the file names on an array then loop using math.random*array.size to choose randomly a path of a song
look at this it may help [getting all filesnames on folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694385/getting-the-filenames-of-all-files-in-a-folder)

Answer (score 1):

```
 List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();


 File[] files = new File("/path/to/the/directory").listFiles();
 //If this pathname does not denote a directory, then listFiles() returns null. 

 for (File file : files) {
  if (file.isFile()) {
    results.add(file.getName());
  }
 }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
   String sound=results.get((int) (Math.random()*result.size()));
   play(sound);
 }
```

tell me if it work.

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: what other way you need ? do want it to play continuously ?with only one event ? @an_barce