# compare values in an arrayList with c: drive in windows

Tags: java, arraylist

am trying to compare all the values in my arraylist with all the files in my c:drive

but the code below does not work

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("*.txt,*.docx");
    File file = new File("c:\\*.txt");
    if (file.equals(list)) {
    System.out.println("file was found");
    }else{System.out.println("nothing was found");
    }
```

so the idea is that anytime i run my the code my arraylist would compare itself with my c: drive and list all files that has the extension of "docx and txt" out.

i realised that when i use wildcards it didn't work.

Comment: You will need to get a list of all the filenames http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694385/getting-the-filenames-of-all-files-in-a-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a [FileNameFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) to get all files that pertain to your requirements

Here is an example of getting all `*.txt` files from current directory. You can implement FileNameFilter to create your own filter that will work on your List.

```
    File f = new File("."); // current directory

    FilenameFilter textFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            String lowercaseName = name.toLowerCase();
            if (lowercaseName.endsWith(".txt")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };

    File[] files = f.listFiles(textFilter);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: the code gave me exactly what i wanted after few modifications. thanks a million.