# recursively display all files with certain extension

Tags: java, recursion

i was given some psuedocode to get me going but I can't figure it all out. the extension is assigned to the variable "ext"

```
If f.isFile() is true, then
 If f.getPath() ends with the extension, then
    Add f.getPath() to the foundFiles array list
 Return // this is the end of recursion
Else // This must be a directory
 For each subFile in f.listFiles() // This gets all the files in the directory
    Call findMatchingFiles(subFile) // This is the recursive call
```

this is what I have so far and can't seem to fill in the blanks. any tips or help is greatly appreciated.

```
public void findMatchingFiles(File f) {

    if (f.isFile() == true) {
        if () {

        foundFiles.add(f.getPath());
        }

        return;
    } else {
        for ( : ) {
            findMatchingFiles(subFile);
        }

    }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void findMatchingFiles(File f) {

    //i added this. you need to change it to be whatever extension you want to match
    String myExtension = ".exe";

    if (f.isFile() == true) {

        //i added this block. it gets the extension and checks if it matches
        int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
        String extension = fileName.substring(i+1);
        if (extension.equals(myExtension)) {
            foundFiles.add(f.getPath());
        }
        return;
    } else {

        //i added this. it gets all the files in a folder
        for (File subFile : f.listFiles()) {
            findMatchingFiles(subFile);
        }
    }
}
```

The code above should solve your problem. The two things you were missing were:

1. How to get the files in a folder. A google search found this: [Getting the filenames of all files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694385/getting-the-filenames-of-all-files-in-a-folder)
2. How to get the file extension. A google search found this: [How do I get the file extension of a file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571223/how-do-i-get-the-file-extension-of-a-file-in-java)

I plugged those both into your code and it should work fine. Also note the variable I added named `myExtension`. You will need to change this variable to reflect whatever extension you actually want to match.