# Java interact with windows cmd

Tags: java, windows, cmd

I've searched for similar questions, but despite there where a lot with a similar title all have asked something different.

In my case I want that my java program interact with the terminal (Windows) by writing command and reading the response.

I've found the class `ProcessBuilder`, but does not seem that do what I want

What I' m searching for is something so:

1. start the `cmd` at some given position (like `C:\Users\federico`)
2. issue a command (`dir` or `cd desktop`); this should not open a command prompt window
3. read any output that command may result in

and so on, up to the user's exit from the program.

Comment: This is what a batch file is for.  Where does Java's capabilities play into all of this.

Comment: You want to "digit" a command?  What does that mean?

Comment: @NickZiebert i do not want only to execute a cmd command but olse read what cmd answered (ex: i put in my batch these instruction:  1: cd C:/Users/federico   2:dir.    What i want is that my program read which are the subdirectory, i do not want that a cmd is open with that cubDirectory.

Comment: @ajb i want that the user can write in a text commands and my program execute that commands on cmd and print the result in another textfields: I want to do what i normally do on cmd, easily running my program

Comment: It sounds like you want to write a program that works like a Command Prompt window?  This won't be easy.  I think that most of the commands can be handled with `ProcessBuilder`, but you'll need to handle special commands like `cd` yourself.  You'll need to parse it, figure out what to set the current directory to, and set up future `ProcessBuilder` processes so that they start in the new current directory.  There will probably be other commands that your program will have to handle specially.  Voting to close as "too broad" because this is too big a question to answer here.

Comment: @fedi98 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694385/getting-the-filenames-of-all-files-in-a-folder is all I got.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you simply don't know the English terms for this: what you're looking for is a way to execute commands in the OS, which is called "exec" in every programming language I know of, including Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)

Comment: I don't think this is right.  He mentions `cd desktop` as one of the commands he'd like to give the user, and you can't simply exec that.  Sounds to me like he wants to write his own equivalent to cmd.exe.

Comment: quite, but issuing the command "cd desktop" doesn't do anything on its own, and is *not* the same as "changing the current working directory", so in lieu of additional details, the question "how do I run a command" is still "you use exec"

Comment: But he didn't ask "how do I run a command".

Comment: No, he (or she) used a few more words: "I want that my java program interact with the terminal(windows) by writing command and reading the response" is the description of every `exec` out there.

Comment: Sorry, but I interpret it differently.  And we're both just guessing, so we'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans you are right. I knew the method exec but i always thought that it does something different. I searched and i discovered this:                                                                                              Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c dir", null, new File("C:\\Users\\federico")); and this, up to now, work great for me. thank you

Comment: @ajb, i meant that the user can walk through directories. i handled this doing Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c dir", null, new File("C:\\Users\\federico\\Desktop") when the user writes cd Desktop (i control which is the input, and if the command is cd, i change the working directory)