# Make an Array of the Names from the Image Folder (java and Spring boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've got an image folder in my resources folder and there are pictures stored.

Now I want an Array in my Java Class who has stored the names of each Picture in the folder. Later I want to test if a picture name equals a specific word, but that can I handle by myself. I just dont know, how to make the 'PictureName' Array.

I am using Spring boot with Java.

Comment: show us what you have so far

Comment: This is already answered here : [https://stackoverflow.com/a/5694398/8536103](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5694398/8536103)

Comment: That is is, nothing.. I dont know the command of reading your Images when you dont know the specific name of it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily:

```
File folder = new File("your_path");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
        if(file.isFile()){
            System.out.println("File Name:" + file.getName());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File folder = new File("C:\\path\\to\\your\\folder\\");
List<File> files = Arrays.asList(folder.listFiles());
```

Insert the path to the folder that contains all your images in the first line.
In `files` List you will find the list of all the images in your folder in objects of type `File`.

Every `File` object has the method `getName()` that will return the name of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try somethings like this(Check if f is file( because it can be dictionary):

```
File folder = new File("yourPathTofolder");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        for (File f: listOfFiles) {
            if (f.isFile()) {
                System.out.println("File " + f.getName());
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

1. First provide your folder path, that will contain all the images.

`File folder = new File("your/path");`

2. Store all files in `File` type array variable.

`File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();`

3. Iterate over variable to get `filename(s)`

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
     if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
       System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
     } else  {
       System.out.println("Not a File..");
     }
   }
   ```

   **Full code**

   `File folder = new File("your/path");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 
       for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
         if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
           System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
         } else  {
           System.out.println("Not a File..");
         }
       }`

Hope that helps.